# General approach for user-extensible move effects on turn-based games?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, dsl, purescript

A simple form of a turn-based game can be abstracted in a functional language as:

```
data Player 
  = PlayerA
  | PlayerB
  deriving Show

data Game state move = Game {
  start :: state,
  turn :: (move, move)
    -> state
    -> Either Player state}

play :: [(m, m)] -> Game s m -> Maybe Player
play moves game 
  = either Just (const Nothing) 
  $ foldr tick (Right (start game)) moves where
    tick move (Right state) = turn game move state
    tick move p = p
```

In that setting, a game has an initial state, a type of valid moves, and a function that computes the next state (or a winner) based on the move picked by each player on that turn. This definition is enough to create any kind of turn-based game - from something as simple as rock-paper-scissors, to a fully featured battle RPG. Here is a simple duel game:

```
data DuelMove = Punch | Guard | Rest

data DuelState = DuelState {
  p1hp :: Int,
  p2hp :: Int}
  deriving Show

duel :: Game DuelState DuelMove 
duel = Game start turn where

  start = DuelState 4 4

  turn (ma,mb) (DuelState p1 p2) 
    | p1 <= 0 = Left PlayerB
    | p2 <= 0 = Left PlayerA
    | otherwise = attack ma mb where
      attack Punch Punch = Right (DuelState (p1-1) (p2-1))
      attack Punch Guard = Right (DuelState (p1-2) (p2+0))
      attack Punch  Rest = Right (DuelState (p1+0) (p2-2))
      attack Guard Punch = Right (DuelState (p1+0) (p2-2))
      attack Guard Guard = Right (DuelState (p1+0) (p2+0))
      attack Guard  Rest = Right (DuelState (p1+0) (p2+2))
      attack  Rest Punch = Right (DuelState (p1-2) (p2+0))
      attack  Rest Guard = Right (DuelState (p1+0) (p2+2))
      attack  Rest  Rest = Right (DuelState (p1+2) (p2+2))

main :: IO ()
main = print $ play moves duel where
  moves = [
    (Punch, Punch),
    (Punch, Guard),
    (Guard, Punch),
    (Rest, Rest),
    (Punch, Guard),
    (Guard, Punch),
    (Punch, Rest)]
```

There is a problem with that abstraction, though: adding new moves require editing the definition of the the types and, consequently, the source-code of `turn`. This is not sufficient if you want to allow your users to define their own moves. Is there any abstraction for similar turn-based games, which elegantly allow for new moves to be added without modifying the original code?

Comment: outside module extensibility can be achieved using _type-classes_.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is to parameterize the `turn` function. Thus:

```
type DuelMovePlus = Either DuelMove

turn :: (a -> DuelMove -> Either Player DuelState)
     -> (DuelMove -> a -> Either Player DuelState)
     -> (a -> a        -> Either Player DuelState)
     -> DuelMovePlus a -> DuelMovePlus a -> Either Player DuelState
turn userL userR userLR = \case
    (Left  l, Left  r) -> {- same code as before -}
    (Left  l, Right r) -> userR  l r
    (Right l, Left  r) -> userL  l r
    (Right l, Right r) -> userLR l r
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this... how does this allow different users to compose their moves into a single game, for example, without touching the code of each other?

Comment: @Viclib It doesn't. Also, you didn't ask for that; also also, it doesn't sound possible. If I want to define a `SweepKick` move without knowing about your moves and you want to define a `KarateChop` move without knowing about my moves, what is the poor engine supposed to do when it sees a `SweepKick` vs. `KarateChop`? Neither of us has told it what should happen in that case.

Comment: Yep, I think I'm not expressing myself well, but that is for the fact I don't understand well the problem I'm solving. I understand the issue you raised and it makes sense. It also made me realize that it is not true that both players don't know the code of each other - the last player to propose a new move does know about all the previous implemented moves, so, in theory, he should specify the interaction with all the previous moves. I'm gonna think about that now...

Comment: @Viclib In that case, it is straightforward to extend the parameterization technique to handle arbitrary `Either`s rather than just `Either DuelMove`. Then it is easy to do what you ask; each programmer that adds new moves also adds a layer of `turn`. (e.g. the second progammer writes `turn secondUserL secondUserR secondUserRL (turn firstUserL firstUserR firstUserRL)`.

Comment: Yep, it might be. I think I'm getting there, let me just think for a while.

Comment: Well, I'm really confused, the problem seems much harder than I thought. For example, suppose there are 120 moves, each one with a type. Then I decide to add: `Mirror: if hit by an energy move, reflects its damage.` - now, how could adding such a move work? I'd have to add 120 layers, and each layer would basically duplicate the existing code for the old moves. Looks like my approach overall is simply not well thought. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: To be clear: I think my whole design is flawed. Maybe it would be better if I just asked directly how you would create a turn-based game on which you can add new moves incrementally, without having to edit the old code, nor add a new number of clauses proportional to the length of the old code. I think this might have something to do with the expression problem?